# Equations in normal LaTeX to MathJax formatting

Tags: math-mode, formatting, mathjax

To use the `align` environment in a document one does something like:

```
\begin{align*}
x &= \sqrt{4^2-1^2} \\
  &= \sqrt{15}.
\end{align*}put
```

However, to achieve the same desired output on a webpage which uses `MathJax` to render math, as [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com) does:

```
\[
  \begin{align*}
x &= \sqrt{4^2-1^2} \\
  &= \sqrt{15}.
  \end{align*}
\]
```

must be done.

I want to save in some `tex` files the contents of some possible post for webpages which use `MathJax`, so the post would be whatever is between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. But also, I want these documents to be compilable using `pdflatex`.

In order to achieve that, either the `\[ \]` or the `align` (and the like) environment must be redefined.

How to do so?

Comment: You do not need the `\[` and `\]` for MathJax to recognize this. You have not give your MathJax configuration, but as long as `processEnvironments` is true in the tex2jax section of your configuration, then it should pick up the `\begin` directly.

Comment: @DavideCervone I've realized that after I posted this. If you put your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need the `\[` and `\]` for MathJax to recognize this. You have not given your MathJax configuration, but as long as `processEnvironments` is `true` in the `tex2jax` section of your configuration, then it should pick up the `\begin` directly.  See the [tex2jax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html) section of the configuration documentation.

Answer (score 4):

One idea is to have a conditional test; if the conditional is true (mathjax document), then nothing is done; if it is false (pdflatex document), then `\[` and `\]` are `\let` to `\relax`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newif\ifmathjax
\ifmathjax\relax
\else
\let\[\relax\let\]\relax
\fi
\mathjaxfalse% for pdflatex
%\mathjaxtrue% for mathjax

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{align*}
x &= \sqrt{4^2-1^2} \\
  &= \sqrt{15}.
  \end{align*}
\]

\end{document}
```

Of course, this implies that in your document you can't simply write

```
\[ expression \]
```

you'll need `\begin{equation*}` expression `\end{equation*}`.

Comment: That can be a problem. Is it possible to redefine the `align` environment instead? The only thing which is needed is to allow the syntax `\[\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}\]`

Comment: Just checked. It seems that there's no problem with using the `align` environment without the `\[ \]`. My question is useless.

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the `mathjax` documentation. `align*` should work just fine. But it is not supported by `mathjax` by default. If I call it as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
```

then things like `align*` works just fine.